# WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 and analytics configuraton, Error : "api_request_summary"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have configured WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 AM Analytics as per following document - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics

I could see generated analytics data on analytics server carbon admin dashboard under Home>Manage>Interactive Analytics>Data Explorer but when I try Statistics on API Publisher or store it is giving following error in the log of api manager: please advise. thanks.

[2017-01-06 03:56:34,768] ERROR - usage:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException: Error occurred while querying from JDBC databaseERROR: relation "api_request_summary" does not exist
  Position: 34
[2017-01-06 03:56:48,820] ERROR - usage:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException: Error occurred while querying from JDBC databaseERROR: relation "api_request_summary" does not exist

Comment: Looks like `api_request_summary` table is not available in STATS_DB. Check that.

Comment: Thanks @Bhathiya, I was able to figure out. I was having two different database for wso2am_stats_db defined and configured with datasources for API manager and API Manager analytics, where as both should be configured for same db, Once i changed the datasource (WSO2AM_STATS_DB) of API manager  to same database which is configured with analytics. It worked and i was able see all analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Bhathiya, I was able to figure out. I was having two different database for wso2am_stats_db defined and configured with data-sources for API manager and API Manager analytics, where as both should be configured to same db. Once i changed the data-source (WSO2AM_STATS_DB) of API manager  to same database which is configured with analytics. It worked and i was able see all analytics on store and publisher.

got some help from following references: 
[How to manage billing with WSO 2 AM (2.0.0)](http://How%20to%20manage%20billing%20with%20WSO%202%20AM%20(2.0.0))