# Error Configuring WSO2 data analytics server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm currently experimenting/working on WSO2. What i'm trying to do is to have Data Analytics server configured. I started by following the below specified URL

- https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#9d6747f5c0074928b18599abe472987d (Quick Steps)

After performing all the steps, i get the following issue on APIM cmd prompt

[image]

YES Its pretty evident from the error that no such table exists BUT that is **exactly** the issue i'm facing. What could really be the cause here?

Consider the following points:

- I've not followed **ALL** the steps mentioned on
  https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Getting+Started (BUT are they
  required?)
- In the installation prerequisites for DAS, JDBC-compliant Connector for Java is required which I've not yet installed (BUT its not mandatory at the same time)
- Most of the QUICK STEPS for the configuration of DAS in the specified URL i.e. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+APIM+Analytics#9d6747f5c0074928b18599abe472987d where already in place and i only had to

  - Set Up JDK, ANT, Maven
  - enable the analytics section in the **API-M_HOME/repository/conf/api-manager.xml**
  - add **log4j.rootLogger=, DAS_AGENT** to **API-M_HOME/repository/conf/log4j.properties**
  - add snappy-java_1.1.1.7.jar to **DAS_HOME\repository\components\lib**

Yet the issue persists, Do let me know of what you think. Thank you

Comment: can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499073/wso2-api-manager-2-0-0-and-analytics-configuraton-error-api-request-summary

Answer (score 0):

Since you are following quick start guide please extract the WSO2 API Manager and the WSO2 API-M Analytics distributions (zip files),  to the same directory (preferably an empty directory).

Also, you need to generate some traffic to the published APIs in order to analytics server to create this table for the first time.

Comment: Thank you for responding, when you say we need to generate traffic for DAS, how much traffic exactly are you talking about? its been days since we configured the DAS and yet the same prompt appears to generate traffic.

Comment: Any answer for me?